# How to create an Iterable of semi-homogenous Integers that sum to a max in Scala?

Tags: scala

**In scala; given a maximum sum value and a maximum element value, how can an `Iterable` of elements be created such that the elements add up to the maximum sum?**  The Iterable should have the smallest size possible.

As an example, given

```
val maxSum = 47

val maxElementValue = 10
```

How can the following Iterable be created:

```
Iterable(10, 10, 10, 10, 7) //sum to 47
```

Other examples:

```
val maxSum = 9
val maxElementValue = 10
Iterable(9)

val maxSum = 11
val maxElementValue = 5
Iterable(5, 5, 1)
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Is there any other rule about the generated elements? like it is ok to all be the max element value?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez They can all be the max element value, but the sum of the elements must equal maxSum.  Also, the Iterable should be the minimum length necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
   ((maxSum % maxElementValue) :: List.fill(maxSum / maxElementValue)(maxElementValue)).filterNot(_ == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are in `2.13` you can use `unfold`

```scala
def elementGenerator(maxSum: Int, maxElementValue: Int): List[Int] =
  Iterator.unfold(maxSum) { remainingSum =>
    if (remainingSum == 0)
      None
    else if (remainingSum <= maxElementValue)
      Some(remainingSum -> 0)
    else
      Some(maxElementValue -> (remainingSum - maxElementValue))
  }.toList
```

You may also consider just returning the **Iterator** or using a **LazyList** if you do not need to keep all the elements right now but just know how to generate them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.unfold` for this:

```
// Use `Iterator.unfold` if you want an Iterator instead of a List
List.unfold(maxSum) { remaining =>
  if (remaining <= 0) None
  else {
    val nextElement = math.min(maxElementValue, remaining)
    Some(nextElement -> (remaining - nextElement))
  }
}
```

returns

```
List(10, 10, 10, 10, 7)
```

See it on [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BhvsmAFNQwOKS4i4OjOFJg).

Comment: I haven't noticed that **List** also had an `unfold`  method.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: It's defined on [IterableFactory](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableFactory.html#unfold%5BA,S%5D(init:S)(f:S=%3EOption%5B(A,S)%5D):CC%5BA%5D), so a lot of the usual collections have it too.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function can do the trick

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def elementGenerator(maxSum: Int, maxElementValue: Int, currentElements: Seq[Int] = Seq.empty[Int]) : Seq[Int] =
  if(maxSum == 0 || maxValue <= 0)
    currentElements
  else if(maxSum < maxElementValue)
    currentElements :+ maxSum
  else
    elementGenerator(maxSum - maxElementValue, maxElementValue, currentElements :+ maxElementValue)
```

Comment: `++`  can be pretty slow depending on which **Iterable** the runtime picks. It would be better to use a **List** and prepend each element and then reverse or use something like **Vector** and append each element. In any case, prefer a concrete collection. -- also, never expose internal details of recursion in the original function, use an internal function for accumulators.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks, updated accordingly.

Comment: Prepend on **Seq** can still be slow, it is not a concrete collection, just another _(useless for me)_ interface.

Answer (score 0):

Presented mostly as a "well, it works but you really don't want to do it this way" alternative :)

```
Iterator.fill(maxSum)(1).grouped(maxElementValue).map(_.sum)
```